# Create a Webhook when installing an app in Shopify

Tags: php, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm developing an app to sync Shopify product list with my own DB.
When a product is deleted from Shopify admin, I need to delete it in my MySQL DB.
I think I have to create a Webhook for product deletion.
I know the way to create Webhooks in Shopify admin page, but I'd like to create it when my app is installed.
Please give me your answer if you have any idea.

I've tried to find answers for this problem, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: It depends, if Shopify when Webhooks is configure uses a DB to store the code, then the question is whether you can get access to the table where the Wbhook is stored? On the other if the Webhoos are store in folder/directory where Shopify reads/includes/requires the Webhook from then you need to know the location and drop you Webhook there. Does Shopify document it's internal configuration, internal working of how Webhooks are loaded in the Shopify platform?

Comment: I just typed "shopify api create webhook" into Google, and found [How to Create Shopify Webhooks With the Shopify API Tutorial](https://hookdeck.com/webhooks/platforms/how-create-shopify-webhooks-with-shopify-api-tutorial) in no time.

Comment: Please follow [ask] when asking questions

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for automated **Webhook Subscription via API**. Yes, Shopify does allows that.
You need to Subscribe to the hooks via API call when you app is being installed or autorized by the Shopify store. Please check the Documentations below.

For understanding the webhooks and behaviours: https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks

Apis for Webhook Subscription: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/webhook